# Restrict Textbox from enter numbers from 2 to 998 not working

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox like the follows;

```
<input type="text"  id="rankId" onkeypress="return validate(event)"/>
```

It should only accept values from 2 to 998. I have write a function like that;

```
function validate(key)
{
//getting key code of pressed key
var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
var phn = document.getElementById('rankId');
//comparing pressed keycodes
if (!(keycode==8 || keycode==46)&&(keycode < 48 || keycode > 57))
{
return false;
}
else
{
//Condition to check textbox contains 3 numbers or not
if (phn.value.length <3)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
}
```

The function is working for numbers only and 3 numbers restrictions. How can I restrict it to numbers from 2 to 998? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Call a function in blur event and do like as follows

```
var value =  document.getElementByID("rankId").value;

if(value < 2 || value > 998)
   document.getElementByID("rankId").value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a property `value` of Javascrift for get value of input...

```
  var phn = document.getElementById('rankId').value;
```

Then

```
 function validate(key)
    {
    //getting key code of pressed key
    var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
    var phn = document.getElementById('rankId').value;
    //This is a Javascript!!! and you have to define the function...
    //comparing pressed keycodes
    if (!(keycode==8 || keycode==46)&&(keycode < 48 || keycode > 57))
    {
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    //Condition to check textbox contains 3 numbers or not
    if (phn.length <3)
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: 'value' is a property I guess, not a function.

Comment: Ehhh thanks... I study visited on question's Stackoverflow.. and I always think that was a function